# Why is the if __name__ == "__main__": main() pattern used instead of putting the main code in the if statement?

Tags: python

Although I've been using python for a while, and a common pattern you see is these two statements:

```
def main():
    # Fancy code here 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My question is, why wouldn't you use this pattern instead?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Fancy code here
```

Is this just in case you want to import main from another place? Or is there some other reason you might want to do this?

Comment: Because then you can call `module.main()`, making the code reusable.

Comment: All right, that makes sense. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Wild speculation: some programmers that do this aren't doing it for any practical reason; they're doing it because all of the non-Python languages they've ever used require a main function, and they would feel weird not using it in Python too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another reason is to avoid populating the global scope with variables.

Consider this example:

```
def add_em(arg1, arg2):
    return a + b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = 2
    b = 4
    print(add_em(a, b))
```

Here, the `add_em()` function clearly has a bug: it should return arg1 + arg2, but since the a and b variables belong to the global scope, this bug will likely go undetected until `add_em()` is called from another context. Running the script gives no error:

```
$ python myscript.py
6
```

Using a `main()` function would likely detect this earlier:

```
def add_em(arg1, arg2):
    return a + b

def main():
    a = 2
    b = 4
    print(add_em(a, b))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now the error is detected right away:

```
$ python myscript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

A function is *reusable*, you can call it from other code. Code under the `if __name__` guard can't so be invoked.

It makes testing and encapsulation easier. All you need is

```
import module

module.main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! That does make sense, but when you're just looking at the code it looks a little silly :)